# Kurtosis risk interpretation

Tags: self-study, kurtosis

There is a True or False item that is confusing me a little bit.

Statement says:

"Kurtosis risk (also known as 'fat tails' risk) explicitly describes the situation of having more observations at either extreme of the tails of the distribution than a normal distribution would suggest"

To provide more background:  Kurtosis risk in finance is effectively when you have the presence of fat tails. So it would refer to a platicurtic distribution.

I tend to believe this is false, because it saying at "either extreme", and it should be at both?

Comment: You can have a fat-tailed distribution (relative to the Normal) at one extreme; this would cause Normal-based models to understate the probability of an extreme event in that direction, which seems to me to be a risk.

Comment: But in any case, that would be skewness and not kurtosis?

Comment: Well, presumably both, but the risk doesn't come from the skewness, it comes from the kurtosis.  You can have a distribution skewed right that has thinner tails than the Normal, so you don't have as high a probability of an extreme event in that direction as the Normal would indicate, and presumably the associated asset would be regarded as less risky (in a fat-tail sense) than the Normal model would indicate.

Comment: The usual kurtosis measure, being based on the fourth power of deviation from the mean, does not distinguish between upper and lower tail. So you can have high kurtosis (fat tails refers to leptokurtic, not platykurtic) with either a fat upper tail, a fat lower tail, or both.  Yes, from a finance standpoint, the "upper tail alone" case does not sound bad at all; thus kurtosis "risk" does not necessarily refer to bad possibilities. Instead, it refers to the inability of the normal model to correctly bound the extremes, eg, using +- 3 standard deviations from the mean..